# Edit Suite Bar Links in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: 2016, suite-links

I am looking for any idea how to edit/hide Suite Bar Links in SharePoint 2016 on premise. (Link Webs next to Main Branding text)

In 2013 I was using `SuiteBarLinks` solution, that used Terms links

Comment: In 2016 you change it via powershell

Comment: Can you post some Powershell commands to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately , till now there is no `SuiteBarLinks` solution like [SharePoint 2013 Suite Bar Links Configuration](https://sps2013sbl.codeplex.com/) in SharePoint 2016. But alternatively, you can work with `Suite Bar` via CSS and Jquery as the following :

**To hide Suite Bar Links use the following CSS**

```
#suiteLinksBox {
    display: none;
}
```

**To hide a specific Link in Suite Bar like newsfeed**

```
#suiteLinksBox .ms-core-suiteLink-a[id$='ShellNewsfeed'] {
    display: none;
}
```

**To hide the full Suite Bar**

```
#suiteBar {
    display: none;
}
```

For more details check [Hide Newsfeed, OneDrive and/or Sites from the Suite Bar 
To Add a new link](https://thomasdaly.net/2016/03/05/hide-newsfeed-onedrive-andor-sites-from-the-suite-bar-ribbon-area-for-sharepoint-2013/)

**To Add a new Link at Suite Bar links via Jquery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var customLi = "<li class='ms-core-suiteLink'><a class='ms-core-suiteLink-a' target='_blank' href='https://rootsite/SitePages/Home.aspx'>Home</a></li>";
if(jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").length > 0){
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").append(customLi);
       }
else {
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").html('<ul class="ms-core-suiteLinkList">' + customLi + '</ul>' )
}
</script>
```

Ref : [Customize SharePoint suite bar](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/customize-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/)

Check also, [How to Change SuitBar’s Logo, Text in SharePoint 2016 via PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx) .

**Note :**

- I have applied the above-mentioned code on SharePoint 2013 that I think it's should be working in SharePoint 2016, if you face any issue try to use `Developer Tools F12` to specify the Corrected IDs
- Instead of applying these samples to MasterPage directly , First apply these samples in a Script Editor to a specific page.

Comment: Css is pefect, but not work. I think this is because css styles, you post are in SuiteNav.css, not in CoreV15.css. For customin CSS im using this `<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="/SiteAssets/custom.css" runat="server" after="corev15.css" />`

Comment: Dear @DominikDivák you are right. as I told you I tried this on 2013 so are you tried to use Developer tools (F12) to catch the corrected ID , also I mentioned the PowerShell article for 2016 by waqas in my answer it's for changing the logo and Text http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx

Comment: Hello, yes I have tried catch ID, but noone css styles are applied when they are in SuiteNav.css. Article that you post only shows changing Branding text and logo, but there is no solution for Links :(

Comment: Thank you!! used new link to Suite Bar via jquery. Works Great. Only thing had to eidt the masterpages in mysites as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
#Sites_BrandBar { display: none; }
```

works perfectly fine for me on SharePoint 2016