# Change the Top Bar Links in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, suitebar

In 2016 I have a black bar with the SharePoint text to the right. How can i add links or other content to this area? I have already created a new master template (just a copy of Seattle) but I don't understand where to add the code that will allow me to place links. Can anyone provide some guidance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2016, you can modify the Suite Bar via Powershell and Jquery as the following :

To Add new link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var customLi = "<li class='ms-core-suiteLink'><a class='ms-core-suiteLink-a' target='_blank' href='https://rootsite/SitePages/Home.aspx'>Home</a></li>";
if(jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").length > 0){
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").append(customLi);
       }
else {
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").html('<ul class="ms-core-suiteLinkList">' + customLi + '</ul>' )
}
</script>
```

Follow the answer in below link given by M.Qassas for more information.

[Edit Suite Bar Links in Sharepoint 2016](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194278/edit-suite-bar-links-in-sharepoint-2016)